# How do i add Jquery script file to my web page in visual studio 2012 pro?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have visual studio 2012 pro.
I did in the menu: New > Project > Web > ASP.NET Empty Web Application
Then after project created i did on the solution explorer right click > Add > Web Form

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i have files on my hard disk i downloaded: jquery-advanced-news-ticker-master
The files i have are:

index.html file
Two JS files
And one json file

Downloaded the jquery script from [here](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/text-scroller)

The first one: jQuery Advanced News Ticker

But how do i use it with my Web Application ? I want to upload this html page to my already exist web site so i can see the text moving like marquee effect.

EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.newsticker').newsTicker({
        row_height: 48,
        max_rows: 2,
        speed: 600,
        direction: 'up',
        duration: 4000,
        autostart: 1,
        pauseOnHover: 0
    }); // This starts the news ticker
});
```

Added some options to mystuff.js but getting error in the chrome:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Things you can try:
If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
Enable directory browsing.
Go to the IIS Express install directory.
Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.
Run appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the site level.
Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     DirectoryListingModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://localhost:62939/
Physical Path      D:\C-Sharp\Web\WebApplication1\WebApplication1
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\bout0_000\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\WEBAPPLICATION1

More Information:
This error occurs when a document is not specified in the URL, no default document is specified for the Web site or application, and directory listing is not enabled for the Web site or application. This setting may be disabled on purpose to secure the contents of the server.
View more information »
```

Comment: Add a script tag in your head that points to the location of your jquery.

Comment: Adam updated my question with what i did but i don't see anything when it's openning it on chrome. What's wrong ?

Comment: Move the closing head tag below the last of the script tags.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the HEAD tag of your web page (between the `<head>` and `</head>` html tags), add these lines:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="Plugins/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<link href="Content/themes/Smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/newsTicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/mystuff.js"></script>
```

On a new page (called mystuff.js) of javascript you will need to add the code for `document.ready(...)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.newsticker').newsTicker(); // This starts the news ticker
});
```

The News Ticker has too many options to go over here. Look at their [website](https://github.com/risq/jquery-advanced-news-ticker) for more details.

---

**UPDATE**

It should look something like this when you are done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Plugins/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/Smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/newsTicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mystuff.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <ul class="newsticker">
                <li>Etiam imperdiet volutpat libero eu tristique.</li>
                <li>Curabitur porttitor ante eget hendrerit adipiscing.</li>
                <li>Praesent ornare nisl lorem, ut condimentum lectus gravida ut.</li>
                <li>Nunc ultrices tortor eu massa placerat posuere.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im getting on the line that start with <link a warning: Warning 1 Validation (XHTML5): Element 'link' cannot be nested within element 'html'

Comment: Before doing this make sure you create a folder js and put your script files in it (add them to the project) you could also use the script folder.

Comment: To answer your question, you have to put this in the <head> not the <HTML>

Comment: cdwaddell look my question updated it now the head is inside the html already. I didn't change it.

Comment: Adam ok used your  updated part. The warning is gone. Now i don't get also any errors on the chrome. But i don't see anything yet. Do i need to use options of the script first to see anything ?

Comment: Look at the updated code (which I just added the list that the news ticker requires. You need to read and follow the instructions for the news ticker. [https://github.com/risq/jquery-advanced-news-ticker](https://github.com/risq/jquery-advanced-news-ticker)

Comment: Adam i did look at your last update and it worked i saw the text in the opened chrome page. But then i added some options to the mystuff.js took the options example from the jquery site and im getting error in the chrome. Why the options are not working ?

Comment: You are going to have to do some testing and debugging to figure out what is going on by yourself. SO is not built for interactive/team built coding sessions.

Comment: Ok im not getting the error now moved the file mystuff.js to the js folder i created in my project. But i see the text static the custom parameters i added to the mystuff.js didn't change anything no scrolling text just static text as before.

Comment: Clear your cache and refresh your browser.